# What is the 4-letter bad word starting with T?

Tags: single-word-requests

The title of an article in goal.com reads the following:

> Raiola: Sir Alex Ferguson called me a t*** during Pogba negotiations

What is this t*** word that fits in the context? It should be a bad word.

Comment: It's not necessarily 4 letters.

Comment: (But a 4-letter term "appropriate" for a woman is "tart".  But it's unclear to me whether Raiola is male or female, and also unclear whether the term was likely only mildly offensive (such as "tart") or more deeply offensive.)

Comment: Maybe it is *twat*

Comment: Probably "twat". Apparently, in British English, "twat" can mean "a stupid or contemptible person".

Comment: I think Raiola is male since he is a football agent.

Comment: @Andy Schweig Thank you so much. The context is definitely British English so I think you are right then.

Comment: Be aware that in American English, it's crude slang for female genitalia.

Comment: If Raiola is male, as the OP has indicated., then *twat* wouldn't make sense. Perhaps *turd*?

Comment: @RichardKaiser: it can be applied to a man (that may even be more common; compare the U.K. usage of "cunt"). The word isn't being used literally.

Comment: I support *turd*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was **twat**. The source you saw was apparently too squeamish to report the full term, but the original report in the Financial Times contained no mincing.

> *Ferguson to Raiola: You’re a twat.*
>   ...
>   Raiola was unfazed, partly because he didn’t know the word.

(Quoted in ["Mino Raiola: meet the super-agent behind Pogba and Ibrahimovic", *Financial Times*](https://www.ft.com/content/548155cc-9bcf-11e6-b8c6-568a43813464), 2016)

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Twat&oldid=737667904),

> The word **twat** is widely used as a derogatory epithet, especially
>   in British English, referring to a person considered obnoxious or
>   stupid. . . . **Twat** is also used in the United States as vulgar slang for the
>   human vulva.

Interestingly, according to [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Twat) the "female pudendum" definition is actually the original meaning, dating back to the 1650s, with the general, less obscene meaning developing in the UK since the 1920s. As the Wikipedia article suggests and @AndrewLeach points out, the more innocuous definition is now dominant in the UK. Since [(Alex) Ferguson](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Alex_Ferguson&oldid=743165087) is from the UK,<sup>1</sup> presumably the non-obscene meaning was intended.

Despite the probable intended meaning, the vulgar meaning of the word likely led many internet outlets to use asterisks in their reporting of the exchange. American English readers would find the term more shocking and, thus, more newsworthy.<sup>2</sup> And, of course, the use of masking means that even those who would not blink at the actual term are led to believe it was something more offensive.

---

<sup>1</sup> Ferguson is Scottish, according to the Wikipedia article linked above.
<sup>2</sup> The fact that the term is being applied to a male would not mitigate the possibility of this more obscene interpretation, as it is not unusual for feminine epithets to be used as insults for males. Compare, for example, *pussy* (also slang for female genitalia) or *sissy* (babytalk for *sister*).

Comment: It may be worth emphasising that in Britain, *twat* is not a particularly strong insult, as it means "stupid" **far** more often than it's intended to have the ...um... other meaning. In 300 years, it really has been watered down.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks, I've edited to try to make that clearer. Do you think the average British English speaker would be aware of the other meaning, or is this one of those divided-by-a-common-language things?

Comment: I just realized the question is on hold (doh!) but I'm still curious about the varying perceptions of the term.

Comment: Oh, I'm sure the meaning is buried in people's subconscious generally. It certainly can be used in its original sense, but the meaning the word should have is governed by the context. Here, the context is definitely "idiot". The other meaning is usually intended literally, and I've only seen it immediately preceded by the word *her*.